# How do I use only a taxonomy term in the path alias?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have content that is tagged with multiple terms from the same vocabulary. 
How can I use only the first term the node was tagged with, in the URL structure, e.g. domain.com/first/term/with/depth/node-title?

I am trying to do this with the Pathauto module and Drupal 8, but I can't figure it out. It either grabs all the terms used in that node or none.

Answer (score 1):

I gave this a try and the following pattern seems to be working:

[node:field_tags:0:entity]/[node:title]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked. It includes all parents and term of the first entry. If you are using unlimited terms in node, the rest will be ignored.

/[node:field_term:0:entity:parents:join-path]/[node:field_term:0:entity]/[node:title]